# Does ec2 use the whole cpu listed here?

Tags: amazon-ec2

[image: vCPU Count, difference in Clock Speed and Physical Processor]

I'm using m3.medium and wonder if the cpu listed in the image is wholly dedicated to me.

If not, how many percentages of cpu power is dedicated to me?

Answer (score 1):

From [Amazon EC2 instance types](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/):

> Each vCPU is a hyperthread of an Intel Xeon core for M4, M3, C4, C3, R3, HS1, G2, I2, and D2.

Each Amazon EC2 instance is launched on a "host" computer, which may have many CPUs. Each instance will receive the listed number of *virtual CPUs*. This is different to the concept of a "whole CPU".

Comment: to clarify OPs probable concern about shared resources/oversubscription, would you concur that it's accurate to say that an EC2 instance has access to, essentially, the full compute power of ${vCPU} number of cores on a ${PhysicalProcessor} CPU?

Comment: They are "hyperthreaded cores", which is different to "number of cores" of a physical CPU. The bottom line is that an instance has a certain amount of compute, and users should pick an Instance Type that meets their particular compute requirements. So, instead of starting at the CPU, they should start with their requirements (eg transaction load), measure performance and adjust accordingly.

Comment: +1 for hyperthreaded reminder... that's significant.  The overriding point prompting my comment, though, is that the (virtual) cores allocated to your instance are not shared with other instances.  There was a lot of FUD about that back in the day, with smaller instances showing "stolen" cycles that people erroneously assumed were stolen by neighbors, when in fact it was just EC2 provisioning you on a machine faster than what you were paying for, and the hypervisor throttling your CPU down to the correct level.

Comment: Correct -- EC2 is not "overprovisioned", so nobody will steal your CPU cycles or RAM. One pseudo-exception are T1 and T2 instances where there is a 'burst' capability -- I'm not sure what happens if everybody bursts at the same time. At the other end of the scale, when using a `c4.8xlarge` instance, you can control the P-state and C-state of the processors, which permits overclocking within certain temperature parameters.